# Changing the value of the variable from outside of model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
function SearchArticleModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.param = ''}

var searchModel = new SearchArticleModel();
ko.applyBindings(searchModel, document.getElementById("ko-search-module"));


$('.tag-menu').on('click', function(e) {
            showSearch();
            // searchModel.param("tags")
}
```

I need to give a string value `tag` to param. I am not able to do that. I tried but I am stuck at this. I am using knockout for the first time so I am a bit confused. I have my Knockout Model where param value is null. And I trying set the value of param when the following function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ko.observable()` to make your changes affect the UI.

```
function SearchArticleModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.param = ko.observable()
}

var searchModel = new SearchArticleModel();
ko.applyBindings(searchModel, document.getElementById("ko-search-module"));


$('.tag-menu').on('click', function(e) {
        showSearch();
        // searchModel.param("tags")
}
```

Also I'd suggest that you use ko `click` binding instead of `$('.tag-menu').on()`.

```
function SearchArticleModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.param = ko.observable()
    self.setParam = function(){
        self.param('tag'); 
   }
}
```

then in html:

```
<a data-bind="click: setParam"></a>
```

or you can even pass parameter from html binding:

```
<a data-bind="click: setParam.bind($data, 'param value')"></a>
```